# WASLTPARealm authenticator issue

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, application-server, websphere-8

I have Worklight 5.0.6 installed on WAS 8.0.0.5.

I've enabled Worklight Console protection by editing authenticationConfig.xml and adding Worklight Console username and password by editing worklight.properties

Now I'm having a problem with the WASLTPARealm authenticator: The console is using the WASLTPARealm for authentication and it posts the credentials to j_security_check

Could you help me on solving that?
Tks in advance!

Comment: In order to enable WL Console authentication I had to:
1. Edit authenticationConfig.xml
a)  Uncommented <staticResources> for securityTest="WorklightConsole"

b)  Uncommented and changed the test realm from "WorklightConsole" to "WASLTPARealm":
2. Edit and added section in worklight.properties
console.username=<usr>
console.password=<pswd>
3. Move login.html from folder A  to folder B
4. Create a loginError.html in "worklight.war" folder (B)
A = ..\IBM_Worklight_Console_8656872215.ear\worklight.war\WEB-INF\classes\conf
B = ..\IBM_Worklight_Console_8656872215.ear\worklight.war

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation here for setting up a WAS authentication: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/08_06_WebSphere_LTPA_based_authentication.pdf